# Strange C# struct in collection behaviour

Tags: c#, struct, collections

Any ideas as to why this

```
    public Collection<Point> data = new Collection<Point>(){
            new Point{X=10,Y=20},
            new Point{X=20,Y=30},
            new Point{X=40,Y=20},
            new Point{X=10,Y=20}
           };
```

(notice the identical first and last elements)
gives the error

**An item with the same key has already been added.**

If you change the last element to Y=20.1 or anything that makes it different then it works.
Also you can add the elements anyway you like and get the same result.

The problem is obviously due to Point being a value type because it goes away if you define and use a point class and I know that there are problems with using structs in other collection types but this has to do with the difference between value and ref return types. What mystifies me is that this works if the all the structs have different field values.

Comment: You code works as expected ... are you sure you used a `Collection<Point>`?

Comment: Value type equality is by value, see my answer below.

Comment: i compiled and ran your code under .net 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 and it works every time. looks like the issue is different. may be you have custom collection?

Comment: Is this `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`? Or some other class? Please specify.

Comment: It works fine for me too. My full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/zxDhifF8)

Comment: @All you could assume a custom collection considering its reporting an exception - perhaps the OP expects it to be a standard .NET class but is in-fact a poorly named custom class that checks for duplicates.  I believe the issue is the confusion over how a struct is meant to behave when it comes to equality.  Knowing how they behave the OP could then select a suitable collection type for his needs.

Comment: @Adam: We know how structs behave, my only question is: What is the class?

Comment: @Henk it doesn't matter if *you* know how structs behave - my point is that an underlying point to infer from the OP is misunderstanding in how structs work because he elludes that the *problem* is the struct, not how the collection is apparently handling duplicates... if the OP was aware of this, then he could further determine that this collection class, whatever it is, is unsuitable for handling duplicates because it has code for detecting duplicates...

Comment: @All the issue is not the collection. The OP clearly states that what mystifies him is how changing struct values or struct to class suddenly makes it work.  If the desired behaviour is to contain duplicates, then obviously the current collection is not suitable, but this was not directly asked.

Comment: @mikej, please use 'working' (in this case non-working) code for a question. It's not too much trouble to verify with a compiler first.

Comment: @Adam, you're right and you read a little better than I did here.

Comment: Ok - sorry I didn't make it clear that the Collections was in
System.Collections.ObjectModel
The code as presented was copied from a test program and gives the error quoted (and still does). 
I've no idea why the code works "correctly" for some.
Soon after posting the original question in occured to me that it was the difference between value equality and reference equality that was the problem and I do thing think that this is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is because equality of a value type is based on its values - for struct it is equality across all its fields.

Reference type equality is based on the reference itself and thus works.  Changing the struct values to be all different also works.

If you just want a list of stuff, just use `List<Point>`, I think that will accept duplicates.

**Update:**  it looks like your collection class is detecting duplicate entries and you are trying to add duplicates.  If you want to add duplicates, I would say you cannot use this class.

Comment: this is all very interesting but the code sample from question works fine as it is.

Comment: Doesn't matter if his sample code compiles - it might not be exhaustive.  The fact remains he gets his exception because it's detecting equality on the struct - and the OP doesn't seem to understand struct usage.

Comment: See my comments on the question for a further discussion.

Comment: This is the best answer - yes its value v reference types but I am still surprised by the behaviour scince the documentation says
"and allows duplicate elements".
Clearly the implementor was trying to filter out durpicate references to the same object not different objects with identical values (i.e. equality of reference) but ended up excluding two distinct value types that just happen to have the same values.
I'd say that this was a bug rather than a feature...

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a List instead?  I think it should work!

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with this collection class you're using but apparently it doesn't allow multiple items to be in it. As it is with a SET collection. So I guess the Collection you're using is equivalent to:

```
Dictionary<String, Point>
```

but since you you dont have a key it's more like

```
HashSet<Point>
```

Just like your collection class a HashSet requires **all keys** to be **unique**. Like Kieren mentions a List  would be more suitable for you. A list allows multiple entries to be the same.

Indeed if Point was a class it would allow duplicates since Objec1 != Object2 to even if their values are the same.

Comment: For your second code block, replace "`Dictionary<Point>` //Note this isn't possible" with `HashSet<Point>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure on this, but I have a feeling that because the compiler generates a strong Collections item that doesn't require to box/unbox value types, the key check is done on the explicit value type itself, which produces the duplicate key exception?

That's really just a shot in the dark!

Answer (score 0):

What is `Collection` class. It's not .NET Framework library class. Look docs or sources of this class, it would explain the problem.

Comment: @Graham: But that 1 allows dupes.

Comment: Well, `Collection` *is* a Framework class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(d=lightweight).aspx), but it doesn't care if duplicate items are added.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot about ObjectModel namespace. But the code works correct on my PC with all frameworks versions in any rate.